# Creating a matrix with matching x and y labels for columns and rows

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataset that looks something like this, but much larger

```
x.col<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
y.col<-c(2,3,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,5)
response<-c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
ds<-data.frame(cbind(x.col,y.col,response))
```

From these data, I would like to create a matrix in which rows and columns are identical, and values in the cells represent the response between x and y. The output would then look something like this:

```
one<-c(NA,1,0,1,1)
two<-c(1,NA,1,1,0)
three<-c(0,1,NA,0,0)
four<-c(1,1,0,NA,0)
five<-c(1,0,0,0,NA)
mx<-cbind(one,two,three,four,five)
row.names(mx)<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
colnames(mx)<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

*note* that diagnals are "NAs" because they refer to cells in which x and y values are identical

Comment: Not sure why you were not able to install the devel version.  The instructions are pretty much clear at https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation  If you are using an older version of R, it may be better to update it to new R version

Comment: Updating R did it @akrun! Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
Un <-  unique(unlist(ds[1:2]))
m1 <- matrix(0, length(Un),length(Un), dimnames=list(Un, Un))
m1[as.matrix(ds[1:2])] <- ds[,3]
m1 <- m1+t(m1)
diag(m1) <- NA
identical(m1, mx)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset, this may work

```
ds1 <- read.csv('lulc.mean21apr2015.csv')
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
Un1 <- unique(unlist(ds1[2:3]))
res <- dcast(setDT(ds1), factor(id.origin, levels=Un1)~factor(id.dest, 
                levels=Un1), value.var='lulc')
for(j in 1:ncol(res)){
  set(res, i=which(is.na(res[[j]])), j=j, value=0)
 }

res1 <- as.matrix(res[,-1, with=FALSE])
row.names(res1) <- res[[1]]
res1[1:3,1:3]
#      9606 25216 12865
#9606     0     1     0
#25216    1     0     1
#12865    0     1     0
```

Or a modification of the previous solution

```
m1 <- matrix(0, length(Un1), length(Un1), dimnames=list(Un1, Un1))
indx <- do.call(cbind,lapply(ds1[2:3],
          function(x) as.numeric(factor(x, levels=Un1))))
m1[indx] <- ds1[,4]
all.equal(m1, res1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using `xtabs` (though I like @akruns better)

```
levs <- unique(unlist(ds[1:2])) # Find all the unique levels
Res <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(response ~ factor(x.col, levs) + factor(y.col, levs), ds))
Res[lower.tri(Res)] <- t(Res)[lower.tri(Res)]
diag(Res) <- NA
all.equal(as.matrix(Res), mx)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I think the other way may also work with some `t` option, though I didn't try it

Comment: Oops didn't notice it. Sorry

Comment: @David Arenburg, your code runs with my real data, but only with just 10 rows as are in the example dataset.  Your code gives me "Error in model.frame.default(formula = response ~ factor(id.origin, levs) +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'factor(id.origin, levs)')".  Other solutions won't run at all.  A random subset of the actual dataset is here: https://sites.google.com/site/lukelpowell/research/forest-fragmentation-in-brazil/lulc.mean21apr2015.csv?attredirects=0&d=1. The full dataset is probably 100 times larger.  How can I tweak your code to get it to run? Thank you so much.

Comment: Why did you accept this if you can't run it? What's wrong with akruns answer?

Comment: It ran great on the sample data, but not the actual data.  @akrun's code, when run on the real dataset, gave me: "Error in m1[as.matrix(lulc.mean[1:2])] <- lulc.mean[, 3] : 
  subscript out of bounds"

Comment: Ok, I can't check it right now. Let me take a look later.

Comment: @Luke My code was based on assuming that the `x.col` and `y.col` are the `row/column` index.  It could still be made to work by converting each of the columns to 'factor' and then coerce to numeric to get the index, and then replace the index in the dimnames by the actual values.  I posted another solution using `dcast`, which worked on your new dataset.

Comment: @akrun: after two days of trying, I can't get the development version of data.table (v1.9.5+) to install. With the version of data.table I've got running (v1.9.4), I get this error: "Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : could not find function "setDT"".  Banging my head on the wall here.  It would be much appreciated if you could come up with a solution that doesn't require a development version of a package.

Comment: @Luke Your earlier comment (removed) seems to indicate that my code worked with devel version.  Also, I have posted a modified version of my previous solution (if you check my post) which gives the same result as the dcast function.  `setDT` would work with `v1.9.4`.  If not use `as.data.table` and `dcast.data.table`

Answer (score 2):

One approach using `outer`:

```
f = function(u,v) 
{
    res = subset(ds, x.col==u & y.col==v)$response
    ifelse(length(res)==0, 0, res)
}

m = outer(1:5, 1:5, Vectorize(f))
mx = m + t(m)
diag(mx) = NA
rownames(mx)=colnames(mx)=1:5

#   1  2  3  4  5
#1 NA  1  0  1  1
#2  1 NA  1  1  0
#3  0  1 NA  0  0
#4  1  1  0 NA  0
#5  1  0  0  0 NA
```